# how to append clicked li text in div box?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have the following html :-

```
<span id="event">
<ul>
    <li>Activities
    <ul>
        <li>Physical1
        <ul>
            <li>Cricket
            <ul><li>One Day</li>
            </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</span>
<div id="activity"></div>
```

i want to set the click event on every li using jquery click function
it works perfect but i want to set this li text in `#activity` div
here is what i have tried:

```
$("#event ul li").live("click", function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    alert($(this).text());
    $("#activity").append($(this).text());
    return false;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Va5E4/7/

now problem in them when i am click on li its append all the li text in div, i want only clicked li text.
when click on `li` there text append in `div` tag eg:- click on Cricket then cricket append in div when click on One Day append on Div...

how do i do this?
thanks.

Comment: Add your javascript to your question too, not just in JSFiddle

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can grab the first [`childNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/Node.childNodes) of the clicked `li` and append that:

```
$("#activity").append(this.childNodes[0].nodeValue);
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Va5E4/10/)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative using jquery methods

What it does is to make a clone of the clicked node, then remove all the child nodes. What is left is just the the clicked node, so we get only it's text.

```
$("#event li").on("click", function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $("#activity").append($(this).clone().children().remove().end().text());
    return false;
});
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/895qa/)

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look on 
http://jsfiddle.net/Va5E4/12/

```
<div id="event">
<ul><li>Activities
    <ul> <li>Physical1
        <ul> <li>Cricket
            <ul><li>OneDay </li></ul>
            </li> </ul>
        </li> </ul>
    </li></ul>
</div>
<div id="activity"></div>

$("#event ul li").on("click", function(event){
event.stopPropagation();
  var html = $(this).html()   
   var word = html.substr(0, html.indexOf(" "));   
    $("#activity").append(word);
return false;
});
```

Note: This will work for if you have 'single string' as 'value' of 'li' otherwise it won't work.